# How do you define element uniqueness by multiple keys/attributes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, attributes, unique

I have queried my database which gave me an array of hashes, where the keys in the hash are the column names.  I want to keep only the hashes(array elements), that are unique according to multiple (3 columns).  I have tried:

`array.uniq { |item| item[:col1], item[:col2], item[:col3] }`

as well as

> 

```
array = array.inject([{}]) do |res, item|
    if !res.any? { |h| h[:col1] == item[:col1] && 
                       h[:col2] == item[:col2] && 
                       h[:col3] == item[:col3] }
        res << item
    end
end
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's wrong or another way of going about this?

Thanks

Comment: It would be good if you provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you're asking for.  My best guess is that given the array of single-association Hashes:

```
array = [{:col1 => 'aaa'}, {:col2 => 'bbb'}, {:col3 => 'aaa'}]
```

You'd like to have only one Hash per hash value; that is, remove the last Hash because both it and the first one have `'aaa'` as their value.  If so, then this:

```
array.uniq{|item| item.values.first}
# => [{:col1=>"aaa"}, {:col2=>"bbb"}]
```

Does what you want.

The other possibility I'm imagining is that given an array like this:

```
array2 = [{:col1 => 'a', :col2 => 'b', :col3 => 'c', :col4 => 'x'},
          {:col1 => 'd', :col2 => 'b', :col3 => 'c', :col4 => 'y'},
          {:col1 => 'a', :col2 => 'b', :col3 => 'c', :col4 => 'z'}]
```

You'd like to exclude the last Hash for having the same values for `:col1`, `:col2`, and `:col3` as the first Hash.  If so, then this:

```
array2.uniq{|item| [item[:col1], item[:col2], item[:col3]]}
# => [{:col1=>"a", :col2=>"b", :col3=>"c", :col4=>"x"},
#     {:col1=>"d", :col2=>"b", :col3=>"c", :col4=>"y"}]
```

Does what you want.

If neither of those guesses are really want you're looking for, you'll need to clarify what you're asking for, preferably including some sample input and desired output.

I'll also point out that it's quite possible that you can accomplish what you want at the database query level, depending on many factors not presented.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about being vague, but your "second" interpretation was the one I was looking for, thank you

Comment: @Counterfly That's okay; asking clear questions is a skill that takes practice like any other.  I'm glad one of my guesses was correct, and I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If the no. of column is constant i.e. 3 you are better off creating a 3 level hash something like below
where whatever value you want to store is at 3rd level.

```
out_hash = Hash.new

array.each do |value|

if value[:col1].nil?
     out_hash[value[:col1]] = Hash.new
     out_hash[value[:col1]][value[:col2]] = Hash.new
     out_hash[value[:col1]][value[:col2]][value[:col3]] = value
else if value[:col1][:col2].nil?
     out_hash[value[:col1]][value[:col2]] = Hash.new
     out_hash[value[:col1]][value[:col2]][value[:col3]] = value
else if value[:col1][:col2][:col3].nil?
      out_hash[value[:col1]][value[:col2]][value[:col3]] = value
end

end
```

I have not tested the code above its for giving you a idea...